# Key and Mouse Listener for CEditor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to add a listener to one of my plugin views. I need the view to update when a mouse or key event occurs in the CEditor in Eclipse. I have done it by:

((StyledText)((AbstractTextEditor)activeEditor).getAdapter(Control.class)).addKeyListener(l);

But when I change to a different file in the editor the listeners do not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I scrapped the idea of key/mouse listeners and just added a SelectionListener to my Eclipse page. Then created a custom selectionListener that only responded when the selection was in the CEditor.

Made my view class implement ISelectionListener

```
getViewSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(this);

@Override 

public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {

    if(part.getClass() == CEditor.class){

        //Do what I needed 
    } 
}
```

This made it so it only responded to selection changes in my CEditor.